# Listen for any User-Action on a Webapp

Tags: javascript, angular, plc

I have a web based HMI and this is constantly turned on at the machine basically. I need to poll data from a PLC, for which i use exponential backoff with a growing delay. I suspect that this delay will rise over the period where no one is using the machine/HMI. But the moment someone is using the hmi i want to poll data and reset the delay. How can i achieve this globally in angular?

What is the angular way of doing this (if there is), or what is a good place to implement a listener?

Answer (score -1):

You can keep one memory location that will change when someone uses the machine. Initially, you just read that one location and heck if it's true just poll all data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).